# .NET Core Razor - scenario on how to mix C# with html

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

How to I escape the div tags inside my C# if condition so that the compiler accepts the syntax?

I'm trying to start a new column of checkboxes when more than 4 to display. I'm adding a C# `if` condition to deal with a dynamic number of status buttons. Razor is complaining about

```
</div><div class="col-auto mt-1">
```

**ERROR:** RZ1026: Encountered End tag without a starting tag.

```
@{
    int statusCount = 0;
}
    . . . 
<div class="col-auto mt-1">
    <div id="status-failed-ready">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="ReportModel.Status_Ready">
            <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="ReportModel.Status_Ready"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    . . . 
    @if (statusCount++ % 4 == 0) 
    {
        </div><div class="col-auto mt-1"> 
    }
    . . . 
</div>
```

I attempted the following with **ERROR** RZ1025: The text element was not closed.

```
@if (statusCount++ % 4 == 0) 
{
    <text>
        </ div >
        < div class="col-auto mt-1"> 
    </text>
}
```

Comment: A closing tag starts with a forward slash.  An opening tag does not have a forward slash.  The open tag must proceed the closing tag.  You want `div class="col-auto mt-1"></div>` or combine the two : <div class="col-auto mt-1"/>

Comment: seems like you just want the second closing tag to be in else there.  (so that you won't duplicate it...)  If the compiler doesn't understand that you might just suppress the error.  OR alternatively include the whole block of markup in if/else logic.   (you'd be duplicating the static part)

Comment: The reason for no closing tag is because it is further down the line in the code. This is just inserting in the middle of the stream so tags look out of order until you see the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'@:' escapes the tags

**Solution:**

```
@:</ div >< div class="col-auto mt-1">
```